# Pattern for costly precondition check before acting

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, design-principles

Let's say I have a method `DoTheThing()` which requires the precondition-check `CanTheThingBeDone()` to return true. The latter method is time consuming as it accesses the database.

I'm finding it hard to find a perfect way to perform the precondition check effectively (i.e. *once*) while maintaining both readability and API integrity. Observe these examples:

**Example 1:**

```
class System() {
    public void DoTheThing() {
        if (!CanTheThingBeDone()) throw new Exception(...);
        // Do it
    }

    public bool CanTheThingBeDone() {
        // Some time consuming code
    }
}

class Consumer() {
    public void SomeLargerOperation() {
        try {  
            system.DoTheThing();
        } 
        catch (Exception) { 
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
class System() {
    public void DoTheThing() {
        // Do it
    }

    public bool CanTheThingBeDone() {
        // Some time consuming code
    }
}

class Consumer() {
    public void SomeLargerOperation() {
        if (system.CanTheThingBeDone()) { 
            system.DoIt();
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches are ok, but both have drawbacks. In *Example 1*, I'm forcing the consumer to wrap the code in a try-catch for faulty states. These states can be user-triggered so some graceful handling is required. I'm unsure if try-catch for handling user-errors is a good approach.

In *Example 2* I'm handing the responsibility of state-checking over to the consumer, opening up for non-descriptive runtime errors. In *this* example, CanTheThingBeDone() is checked, but when Jimmy enters the team 1 year from now to develop module 2, that might change.

**Example 3:**

```
class System() {
    public bool DoTheThing() {
        if (!CanTheThingBeDone()) return false;
        // Do it 
        return true;
    }

    public bool CanTheThingBeDone() {
        // Some time consuming code
    }
}

class Consumer() {
    public void SomeLargerOperation() {
        if (!system.DoTheThing()) ProduceSomeErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

Now in this example, I avoid try-catch for user errors and prevent the actual Do-code to be executed if invalid state, while ensuring the check-code is run only once. But I feel I'm breaking some naming/coding principle when the method is both performing check and modifying class state (I'm pretty sure it even has a name).

As a fourth example, I could envision a combination of #1 & #2 where both the consumer and `DoTheThing` calls `CanTheThingBeDone`, but then we're doing the work twice.

To sum up - I can't seem to find a best approach. Anyone have a better idea than mine, or suggestions on how to tweak one of these approaches for a better result?

Comment: some questions: 1) What is the expected frequency that `CanTheThingBeDone` returns false? 2) If that happens, will only the call to `DoTheThing` be affected, or will it affect a larger portion of the calling routines?

Comment: It totally depends on what kind of precondition it is and whether it can change. For instance a check if the windows version is windows XP you can safely do during create because it won't change during the life of your object, but a check if a file exists has to be done basically everytime.

Comment: @bart-van-ingen-schenau: In my case it's roughly 50% chance of false. Half of the screens cannot do the action and the button for it will be disabled, so I need to expose CanTheThingBeDone(). It will not affect any other method or class, it's a strictly isolated check and routine.

Comment: @pieter-b: Your commend and other answers here have made me realize this is indeed an important factor. In my case it will not change in the lifespan of the class (Which is short-lived due to it being a web-app), so I should store the result.

Comment: This might be a dupe, either way [this question is very relevant](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184260/where-to-check-that-a-function-actually-did-what-i-told-it-to) (Post-condition rather than Pre-condition but essentially the same question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one rule I like: When in doubt, create an object. C# is an OOP language, not functional after all. So thinking in objects is much better than thinking in methods.

```
public abstract class ExpensiveOperation
{
    bool wasTested = false;
    bool canBeDone = false;

    protected abstract bool Precondition();
    protected abstract void DoExecute();

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (!wasTested)
        {
            canBeDone = Precondition();
            wasTested = true;
        }
        return canBeDone;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (!CanExecute())
            throw new Exception("Cannot execute");

        DoExecute();
    }
}
```

Then you just derive this for your custom operation with precondition. It has many good properties:

- It encapsulates the operation with it's precondition
- Ensures the precondition is called and operation cannot be executed if precondition fails
- Ensures the precondition is called only once no matter what caller does.
- Give caller option to check if it can be executed if necessary
- You just supply the code for precondition and operation, no need to create more code
- Ensures the caller cannot bypass this precondition logic

Comment: I like this solution. I'll keep it in my mental toolbox along with the rule of "when in doubt, create an object" :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the first example whenever possible. This way it's near impossible to forget the check or to forget to handle the error. Also, such a method may return values without resorting to out-arguments.

Why shouldn't I use #2 or #3? Because it is too easy for a `Consumer` to ignore the error, e.g. when the programmer is unfamiliar with `System`'s API. The #2 is especially bad because there is no way to find out whether the operation completed successfully.

If you cannot use the exception system for some reason (e.g. you're writing C which doesn't have one, or you are abstaining from exceptions for performance reasons), then I'd suggest a combination of #2 and #3: You return an error code, but if a programmer knows what he's doing, he may omit any error checks. But you should *also* allow the programmer to explicitly insert the checks beforehand.

Don't think too hard about what an *elegant* solution would look like: first, try to find a *robust* approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some variant of #1. Consumers cannot be trusted to check rules to see if something *can* be run before running something. That adds temporal coupling, even if people remember it.

Ways to improve it:

- **Lazy** - assuming `CanSomethingBeDone` can never change during the lifetime of the object, you can lazily initialize it so you don't check it every call; just once on first use.
- **Decorators** - You should also probably better separate `CanSomethingBeDone` from `DoSomething`, since they are separate responsibilities, which may not change together. A decorator seems like a good approach here. Then you can have a code `DoSomething` and a decorator that checks the rule before calling its wrapped implementation. This keeps things separate and composable. Though this works best when the consumer shouldn't know about the capability at all.
- **No-Ops** - Depending on your usage, it may be preferable to simply do nothing rather than throw an exception if the consumer can't run `DoSomething`. This simplifies the call site, especially if the capability is exposed and you expect that `DoSomething` won't usually be called because it won't be clickable.
- **Don't expose it** - if you've got a composition/plug-in structure, you might be able to hide the entire command when it is unavailable. This though requires a particular architecture and some other constraints that let you know that the plug-in is unavailable early and constantly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you on the decorators (I'm unfamiliar with the term). They are already separated by method. Should they be separated by class through inheritance?

Comment: @nitzor - [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: Yes I looked at the wikipedia page before commenting but didn't quite understand how to apply it to this situation. Is it like making a class A which implements DoSomething and a class B which extends A, implementing CanSomethingBeDone and overriding and wrapping DoSomething?

Comment: @nitzor - yes. Then you have one class that is `DoSomething` and another where `DoSomething` is really "validate that people can do this, and then DoSomething". But the responsibilities are split.

Comment: I would argue against separating the two. The requirement that the precondition has to be checked before the operation is executed creates high coheshion. If you separate it, you create new problem of enforcing that the operation is correctly decorated.

Comment: @Euphoric - Certainly, but I find it hard to believe that there's only _one_ method that needs to have permissions around it. Separating the validation will help it be reused for multiple operations (even if the decorator approach hinders that).

Comment: Ok I appreciate the input. I accepted the answer of euphoric in this question as it was a very concrete solution to my problem, but  I'm definitely taking notes on your more general suggestions here.